# Are paper gold ETFs a scam?

Tags: etf, scams, gold, precious-metals, silver

Recently I found this [website](https://www.usdebtclock.org/#) that has a lot of interesting statistics and among them I noticed something that astonished me : the paper to gold ratio. I am really surprised that there is such a huge ratio between traded gold and physical gold. Here is the value and the definition they give for the paper to gold ratio :
[image: Paper to gold ratio value and definition]
From what I understand that means that if 86 people hold each one 1 ounce of paper gold ETF, only one of them can have access to the physical ounce and the 85 others are left with nothing ? It looks like this system is possible as long as not all paper gold ETFs holder try to access physical gold at the same time. I am not a finance guru so probably I am not getting the whole picture regarding paper gold ETFs but from what I see it is not really reassuring. So here is my question :

**Are paper gold ETFs a scam ?**

The same question can be extended to paper silver ETFs, that has an even higher paper ratio of 171.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. The linked question is identical to the one. The premise of the articles in the linked question is a conspiracy theory, in my opinion. This would be a statistic they'd use to support that view.

Comment: My first question would be what they mean by "actual world production of gold". Over what time period?

Comment: Yes indeed I didn't find this previous question, thanks for the link !